# Time-limiting app for both iOS and Android

Tags: ios, parental-control

My kids spend too much time on their devices. I want to **restrict the time they can use the devices every day**, plus make the devices unavailable at bedtime. A function to instantly stop the devices (when they do not listen) would a plus.

Devices are an iPhone and an Android tablet. I want to monitor and set limits from a web page or Android phone.

I have tried the following two solutions but found limitations:

- Safe Lagoon doesn't work on the iPhone when there is no network connection (schedule not applied, and too much use time reported).
- ScreenTime did not correctly monitor iPhone usage, or ceased to function altogether without any parent report.

Note: I have contacted technical support regarding the problems but no satisfying solution was found.

Any recommendation ?